# Why should I escape the semicolon with find?

Tags: find, options

I'm using bash on Debian. I have to write

```
find -iname "*mp3" -exec cp {}  /media/MP3Player/ \;
```

escaping the final semicolon, or else I get an error.

Comment: [`-exec command ;`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to escape the semicolon so that your *current* shell doesn't see it and use it as a command separator before `find` gets to see it and use it to terminate the command you're sending to `-exec`.

Also, the manual does state in relevant part:

> `-exec utility [argument ...] ;`
>
> [...]
>
> The expression must be terminated by a semi-
>   colon (`;`).  If you invoke find from a shell you may need to quote the semicolon if the shell would otherwise treat it as a
>   control operator.

<sub>n. b. quickly searching my `find` manual shows examples of the `\;` syntax.</sub>